# R: searching within split character strings with apply

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

Within a large data frame, I have a column containing character strings e.g. "1&27&32" representing a combination of codes. I'd like to split each element in the column, search for a particular code (e.g. "1"), and return the row number if that element does in fact contain the code of interest. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
apply(df["MEDS"],2,function(x){x.split<-strsplit(x,"&")if(grep(1,x.split)){return(row(x))}})
```

But I can't figure out where to go from there since that gives me the error:

```
Error in apply(df["MEDS"], 2, function(x) { : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Any corrections or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could also do `grepl('(^|&)1(&|$)', x)`

Comment: Also, since the question asked for the row number, you could use `which(grepl('(^|&)1(&|$)', df$MEDS))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here (in addition to the missing semicolon in the function).

1. `df["MEDS"]` is more correctly written `df[,"MEDS"]`.  It is a single column.  `apply()` is meant to operate on each column/row of a matrix as if they were vectors.  If you want to operate on a single column, you don't need `apply()`
2. `strsplit()` returns a list of vectors.  Since you are applying it to a row at a time, the list will have one element (which is a character vector). So you should extract that vector by indexing the list element `strsplit(x,"&")[[1]]`.
3. You are returning `row(x)` is if the input to your function is a matrix or knows what row it came from.  It does not.  `apply()` will pull each row and pass it to your function as a vector, so `row(x)` will fail.

There might be other issues as well.  I didn't get it fully running.

As I mentioned, you don't need `apply()` at all.  You really only need to look at the 1 column.  You don't even need to split it.

```
OneRows <- which(grepl('(^|&)1(&|$)', df$MEDS))
```

as Matthew suggested.  Or if your intention is to subset the dataframe,

```
newdf <- df[grepl((^|&)1(&|$)', df$MEDS),]
```

Comment: Thank you! Just started learning so, solutions aside, your corrections are really helpful.